# Why does the delta depend on the epsilon in the definition of the limit of a function?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

For example, why can't it be a definition of the limit?

$$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=l\Leftrightarrow( \forall \delta> 0,\exists\varepsilon > 0:|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon \Rightarrow|x-a|<\delta ) $$

Comment: 1) Your definition is wrong. 2) In what you wrote, $\delta $ is independent of $\varepsilon $ however, $\varepsilon $ depend on $\delta $.

Comment: I voted to close because such a question begining with "Why" appeals opinion-based answers. (I understood the question as: "Why was not the proposed "non-definition" chosen, instead of the (*hopefully obviously* non-equivalent) traditional one?"). I hesitated to flag it as a "very low quality question", i.e. unlikely to be salvageable through editing hence to be removed.

Comment: I upvoted because the question is a profound one.  The OP (i.e. original poster) is attempting to expand his intuition.  Personally, I consider intuition to be critically necessary in the study of Mathematics.

Comment: Note that if you take $f(x) = x^2$, by your definition $\lim\limits_{x \to 2} f(x) = 4$ does not hold because not only does neighborhood of $2$ on the x-axis maps to neighborhood of $4$ but also neighborhood of $-2$. So $f(x)=x^2$ being close to $l=4$ does not imply $x$ being close to $a=2$

Comment: This question about [changing the roles of $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198831/slightly-changing-the-formal-definition-of-continuity-of-f-mathbbr-to-mat) in the definition of a limit is likely of interest.

Comment: @AnneBauval There are ~ 250,000 why-questions.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, you have to understand how Mathematicians have come to understand and define the notion of a function approaching a limit $L$, as the variable used in the function approaches a specific element (e.g. the value $a$).

First of all, I specified that the variable [i.e. $x$, used in the function, i.e. $f(x)$] is **approaching** a value (i.e. $x$ is approaching the value $a$).

Note that the function $f(x)$ might not even be defined at the value $a$.  I think that the easiest way to understand what is happening is to think in terms of **neighborhoods**.

The idea is that if you specify a value $\epsilon$, you are requiring that for all $x$ in the domain of the function such that $x$ is in a certain **neighborhood**, that the distance of the value $f(x)$ from the limit $L$ will be less than $\epsilon.$

The variable $\epsilon$ is nothing more than an arbitrarily named variable.  The Mathematical requirement that $f(x)$ is within $\epsilon$ of the limit $L$ is expressed as

$$|f(x) - L| < \epsilon. \tag1 $$

The notion of $x$ approaching $a$ can be Mathematically expressed as

$$0 < |a - x| < \delta. \tag2 $$

Actually, the expression in (2) is something of an oversimplification.  Actually, what is required is that (1) above holds, whenever (2) above holds **and** $x$ happens to be in the **Domain** of the function $f(x)$.

I mention this complication only to warn you that the complication exists.  At this point, I advise you to ignore such a complication.  Instead, simply focus on the idea that the notion of $f(x)$ approaching a limit $L$, as $x$ approaches the value $(a)$ **informally** represents that:

For any $\epsilon$ that is chosen, a value $\delta$ can be found so that if the expression in (2) above is true, then the expression in (1) above is true.

Note that the value $\delta$ in such a circumstance may well depend on the value $\epsilon.$  In fact, you may see a reference to $\delta(\epsilon)$ or $\delta_\epsilon$ to emphasize that as the value of $\epsilon$ changes, the value of $\delta$ may change.

Put simply, the idea is that under the assumption that the limit $L$ exists for $f(x)$, as $x$ appproaches the value $a$, for any arbitrary value of $\epsilon$ a $\delta$-**neighborhood** can be found so that (1) is satisfied whenever (2) is satisfied.

This somewhat obtuse Mathematical notion of the limit of a function was developed to facilitate studying the behavior of functions.

It is important to examine the first portion of (2) above, closely.  The requirement $0 < |x - a|$ indicates that as far as studying the limit of a function, there is no requirement that the function exists at the value $(x = a)$.  Further, even if $f(a)$ does exist, there is no requirment that $L$ equals $f(a)$.

As an illustrative example, consider the function $f(x)$ defined by:

- $f(0) = 1$
- $f(x) = x ~: ~x \neq 0.$

Then, the limit $L$, as $x$ approaches $(0)$ of $f(x)$ is $0$.  This is despite the fact that $f(0)$ equals $(1)$.  In fact, this specific function is an example of a function that has a limit, as $x$ approaches $(0)$, but where the function is **not continuous** at $x = 0$.

Informally, you can regard continuity (or the lack of continuity) as involving whether you can draw the function on a piece of scratch paper, at a specific value (i.e. $x = 0$) **without picking up your pencil**.

Although this definition isn't very precise, it does provide an informal intuition about the whole notion of *continuity*, and it does illustrate the difference between the limit of a function existing as the variable $x$ approaches a certain value (i.e. $x=0$) and the function being **continuous** at ($x = 0$).

The limit does exist, for the bullet-pointed function $f(x)$ above, as $x$ approaches $0$.  As a demonstration of this, consider what happens when you set

$$\delta(\epsilon) = \epsilon.$$

**Then**, for that specific function, as $x$ approaches $0$, whenever the inequality in (2) above is satisfied, the inequality in (1) above will be satisfied.

---

As a further example, consider the function :

- $g(x) = 2x.$

As $x$ approaches $(0)$, $g(x)$ approaches $0$.  The $\epsilon, \delta$ relationship represented in (1) and (2) above, may be established in this situation, for the function $g(x)$, by specifying (for example)

$$\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

One answer to  OPs proposal of a function limit could be it does not met the expectations we usually have of it. Let's consider for instance the constant function
\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}}\\
&\color{blue}{f(x)=l}
\end{align*}
and let's assume we want to calculate $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$, the limit of $f$ at $a=0$.

Here we might want to say: Yes, of course, the constant function $f(x)=l$ has an accumulation point at $a=0$, the function limit at $a$ exists and $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=l$ of course.  In order to justify this statement we recall a common definition of a function limit.

**A common definition:**

- Let $f$ be a function with domain $\mathbb{R}$ and $a$ be an accumulation point of its domain. We define
  \begin{align*}
  \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=l\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad &\forall x\in \mathbb{R}\,\forall \varepsilon >0\, \exists\delta>0: \\
  &0<|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-l|<\varepsilon\tag{1}
  \end{align*}
- We observe when comparing it with OPs proposal, that besides reordering of quantors and conditions we also want to provide some information about *proper candidates* for limit points and about the players $x$ which are allowed to be used approaching a limit.

  - Possible limit points like $a$ above need not necessarily be part of the domain of $f$ but at least they have to be an *[accumulation point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulation_point)* of the domain.
  - Possible candidates $x$ approaching to the limit point are all points of the domain, which are preferrably *near* to the limit point, since they have to met the condition $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

It's not hard to show $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=l$. Given $\varepsilon >0$ we can take an interval around $a=0$ of any size we like, since due to the constant nature of $f$ the image is always $f(x)=l\in (f(0)-\varepsilon,f(0)+\varepsilon)=(l-\varepsilon,l+\varepsilon)$. So we can simply take $\delta=\varepsilon$ and we are finished.

**OPs proposal:**

Now we consider OPs proposal
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=l\Leftrightarrow( \forall \delta> 0,\exists\varepsilon > 0:|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon \Rightarrow|x-a|<\delta ) \tag{2}
\end{align*}
and check, if according to this definition the constant function $f(x)=l$ has a limit at $a=0$.

- Since we have to find for all $\delta > 0$ an $\varepsilon>0$ we set $\delta =1$ and check if we can find an admissible $\varepsilon>0$.
- We want to find an $\varepsilon>0$ which mets the condition $\color{blue}{0<|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon \Rightarrow|x-a|<\delta}$ in (2). But, whichever $\varepsilon>0$ we choose, again due to the nature of the constant function $f(x)=l$ we can always find $x$ far outside the interval $|x-a|=|x|<\delta$ but with
  \begin{align*}
  |f(x)-l|<\varepsilon
  \end{align*}
  so that the condition does not hold for *all* $x\in\mathbb{R}$ for which $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$ is true.

**Conclusion:** Since OPs proposal does not met some common cases we want to cover, it is not that useful.

**Note:** Interestingly the definition of a function limit is not unique. There are two different definitions commonly used. See *[this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979605)* for some information.